# GPS on iPhone 3G not updating during a high speed elevation change

Tags: iphone, sdk, gps, cllocationmanager, elevation

I have written an iPhone app that is supposed to detect rate of elevation change during a high speed fall.  I am using kCLLocationAccuracyBest.  The accuracy is more than adequate during horizontal location changes, but is not giving accurate results during a free fall.  I can however walk the same elevation change (50 feet) and get accurate elevation numbers as I walk.  Is there a problem with measuring a free fall with the iPhone GPS?  I am testing with a 3G.  I am not sure if I would get any better results with 3GS or 4.

It looks like the iPhone GPS calculations can't handle high speed elevation changes.  Is this correct?  Is there any work around?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the phone survive free fall?

Comment: The phone survived.  I built a real nice saftey line with a couple of bungie cords and 50 feet of line.  So, that part of the experiment was successful.  The GPS tracking was not succesful though.  It gave new locations in the delegate every second, but always with the same altitude - even after a 50 foot drop.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Core Motion Framework Reference.  It sounds like to need accelerometer/gyroscope data, not just GPS.

Comment: I agree, was going to add that he should try to enhance available GPS readings with accelerometer data, which should be easily able to quickly detect free-fall and assume constant acceleration until that changes.

Comment: Unless the falling object is outside of the Earth's atmosphere, it will only be in approximate free fall until air resistance becomes significant.

Comment: I started reading up on accelerometer and gyroscope.  All of the posts I saw said that it was difficult to get acceleration correct when moving a small distance and really impossible for large distances such as 100 feet.  That was why I thought GPS made more sense.  All I would need is the altitude evey few seconds, and the rest would be easy.  Unfortunately, the altitude was not showing correctly after a 50 foot drop - even though the delegate was called every second.  I would get good results if I walked the distance downhill, but not with a 50 foot drop.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the iPhone is programmed to more or less ignore changes in elevation when sending updates.  Have you tried setting an NSTimer and polling the CLLocationManager's location property?  Or it may be that it simply doesn't calculate its position frequently enough fotr your purpose.

Comment: I was getting updates every second from the delegate, but the elevation value was not being updated.  This was on a 3G.